# Facebook login with parse is only allowing developer to login

Tags: ios, facebook

I created FB login with parse for iOS and sent the test flight file for testing to other user. To my surprise, only I can login through FB developer account. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What permissions are you asking for? Did you get them approved in review already?

Comment: I followed this tutorial. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook. I am only using these permissions in my code. But why only developer can login and test user cannot. Strange.

Comment: Yeah, all of those need to be reviewed by Facebook before you can ask normal users for them.

Comment: Okay. I will send it for review but we do week need to send .ipa file for review also.

Answer (score 1):

Your app on developer.facebook has sandboxed turn on and thats why its not available to general public.

Do the following

Go to https://developers.facebook.com
Apps > Select your app
Status and Reviews
Select Yes to make your app and all its live features available to the general public.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is selected to "YES". It this related to permissions?

Comment: Your Answer is half right  but when you are in developmental stage, you do not want to send your app .ipa for Status and Review. Status and Review has many requirements that are only filled once your app is ready for market. The easiest way is to add test users and developers for testing in Roles section of Facebook developer page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for quick testing is to add test users and developers for testing in Roles section of Facebook developer page. [image: Adding test users on Facebook]